# How to update an array of strings with only a specific value in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a `MUI TextField` component I am wanting to use as a kind of copy and paste board in the admin area of my app. Sometimes an admin person needs to use the same phrases over and over and so there is a dropdown list of commonly used phrases which can be selected and then they appear in the TextField, or the user can freetype something, For example, they may choose the phrase 'Only these are required' from a dropdown, which then appears in the TextField, but then they also free type on the next line, 'Each day we see 100 of these' I want the initial phrase to stay there and the new one to be added. so the TextField would now look like,

```
Only these are required

Each day we see 100 of these
```

My current implementation involved keeping a state variable 'text' which is updated and used to set the value in the TextField. But it doesn't work as I realised when I use 'setState' to update it, it is updating it with the whole value of the textField which includes anything previous written and not only the new value which is free typed.

Currently I have

```
const [text, setText] = useState(['']); //Array of strings to show in the TextField

//Clear the textField of all entries.
function clearTemplateBox() {
    setText(['']);
  }

//Change function when selecting a string from the dropdown menu - This for some reason works fine, BUT add a , at the start of each new line? not a clue why.
const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    const { value } = event.target
    setTemplate(event.target.value as string);
    let newValue = value + '\n\n';
    setText(prevArray => [...prevArray, newValue])
  };

//When handling free typed input, as event.target.value contains the whole content of the TextField, the whole content is being added to my array text, here I just want to add a new string that is added to the string[]

function handleManualInput( event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) : void {
    setText(prevText => [...prevText, event.target.value]);
  }
```

So if the TextField already contains 4 lines of text and I then freetype 'HelloWorld' I want HelloWorld to be added to the string[] holding the previous 4 lines. I thought it may be possible to somehow compare the string[] to the new string from the event.target.value, but cannot find anything like this.

TextField Code as requested

```
<TextField
        id='template-text-area'
        ref={ref}
        aria-label="minimum height"
        multiline={true}
        rows={28}
        style={{ width: '95%', border: '2px solid lightgrey' }}
        value={text}
        onChange={handleManualInput}
    />
```

Comment: Can you please share the code for TextField Element as well? `<TextField>...</TextField>`

Comment: @ClusterH added it to the question